# What's the benefit of having CF framework and Foundation framework exist at same time?

Tags: objective-c

Since most of them are interchangeable. Would it be easier for programmers to just keep one of them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Core Foundation is C, which means it can easily be used from C code.  Foundation is Objective-C, which can technically be used from C, but it's utterly non-trivial.  The benefit to having the underlying framework written in C is that C can be used with just about every modern programming language and environment.  In a sense, Objective-C, through Foundation, is just another user of Core Foundation.

(The above applies to the parts of Foundation which are built on or bridged with Core Foundation objects.  There are parts of Foundation which are not directly built on Core Foundation.)

Comment: The other aspect is legacy;  CF was a bridge from old world mac to the new world that was in support of Carbon.   That was many moons ago.   At this point, much of CF is actually implemented in Objective-C and the delineation between "CF" and "Foundation" is quite the blur.

Comment: @bbum, I think the move in iOS 9 to an Objective-C framework for Contacts illustrates this quite well, as the AB framework is now completely deprecated.